# How do I say 'It made the hair on my neck stand up' in German?

Tags: english-to-german

How do I say

> It made the hair on my neck stand up' in German?

I'd like to say it in this context:

> The horror film was so scary that it made the hair on my neck stand up.

Comment: -1 for asking a translation. Apart: it's identical to [this question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4607/how-do-i-say-it-made-the-hair-on-my-neck-stand-up-in-spanish) in the Spanish LU site.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The horror film was so scary that it made the hair on my neck stand up.

**Direct, but idiomatic translations:**

Der Horrorfilm war so angsteinflößend, dass...

- ...mir die Haare zu Berge standen.
- ...mir ein (kalter) Schauer über den Rücken lief.
- ...ich eine Gänsehaut bekam.

*This is a wiki answer, so feel free to add to it.*

Answer (score 5):

It would be fine to just write: "...sodass sich meine Nackenhaare aufrichteten", or "...meine Nackenhaare sträubten"

Another possibility would be: "...sodass ich eine Gänsehaut bekam"

Comment: I think the *Gänsehaut* expression is the best one in the given context.

Answer (score 4):

An idiomatic version would be

> ihm standen die Haare zu Berge
>
> ..., dass mir die Haare zu Berge standen.

There's no need to restrict yourself to neck hair in German.